# Casting getResultList to ResultSet

Tags: jpa

I'm seeking some advice here.  I want to know if there is a reason not to do this. As we all know, just because you can do something, doesn't mean that you should.

The application I'm working on is using JPA with existing tables.  Where were can, we are using entities but for a lot of the existing SQL, we are using native queries.  In many of these queries, we are not returning entities, thus the using of native queries.  So, I was wondering if there is a reason not to do this:

```
ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) em.createNativeQuery('NativeQueryString').getResultList();

while (rs.next()) {
    person.setName(rs.getString('name'));
    person.setHeight(rs.getString('height'));
}
```

What we are doing now is:

```
List results = em.createNativeQuery('NativeQueryString').getResultList();

for(Object result : results) {
        Object [] items = (Object[]) result;
        person.setName(items[0].toString);
        person.setHeight(items[1].toString);
    }
```

Or is there a better way to process native queries with JPA?

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason not to cast a JPQL Native Query result to a JDBC ResultSet ? because the result is not a ResultSet, as per the JPA spec, where it's defined as returning Object or Object[] depending on the number of returned cols